# ScanPeripherals with specific service uuid

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to make my app can running in background. 
I've search about that and many references said that I must specified service UUID.

when i do :

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
```

I can get callback `didDiscoverServices`. But when I specified service like this :

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BEAN_SERVICE_UUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
```

It doesn't get callback `didDiscoverServices`.

this is my service UUID

```
let BEAN_SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
```

I've try to change `BEAN_SERVICE_UUID` to uppercase, `"FFF0"`, `"fff0"` but it doesn't work too.

I worked with swift 3

*edited*
this is my `info.plist`

[image]

and this is my general setting capabilities[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot scan for nil services in the background - you must specify the service(s) that you are interested in. From the documentation

> Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are
>   allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must
>   explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the
>   serviceUUIDs parameter.
>
> For your app to continue to receive Bluetooth updates in the
>   background, you need to add a UIBackgroundModes entry to your
>   Info.plist and include the value bluetooth-central in the list.

Also try with :-

```
let BEAN_SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "F0FF")
```

Comment: I've tried to change `BEAN_SERVICE_UUID` like that but nothing happen. I also add UIBackgroundModes etc in my info.plist ( i've updated my questions with info.plist and capabilities screencapture)

Comment: Do your BLE peripheral advertising the Service udid in scan packet?

Comment: I dont know..How to check that programmatically in swift ?

Comment: Print advertising data in centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)

Comment: Ok, I did `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])` and then the result is `["kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1, "kCBAdvDataServiceData": {
    FE9A = <00e68269 25025e66 508f5199 2e036a56 01804440>;
}, "kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs": <__NSArrayM 0x170247a70>(
FE9A
)
]`   So, how to read that log? I mean, is `BEAN_SERVICE_UUID` that I define is advertised in BLE peripheral?

Comment: try with FE9A now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144742/discussion-between-himanshu-and-susy-valentina-rahardjo).

Comment: @Himanshu I want to fetch Bluetooth device which is connected to iPhone and it's name. But i'm not getting name. Can you please suggest how to pass serviceUUID and what to pass  for scanForPeripherals and get name of connected device?